# pybind11 in Visual Studio 2019 - "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing example"

Tags: c++, pybind11

I have tried to build a simple module for Python (I have python37 x64) using C++ in [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019) (Release x64) and pybind11 (pybind11-2.6.1).

I did all setup (added libraries, set up DLL to pyd) and the compilation was successful, however when loading the example.pyd to Python using [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29) IDE it gave me the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing example: The specified module could not be found.

VS2019

    #include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

    int add(int i, int j) {
        return i + j;
    }

    namespace py = pybind11;

    PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
        m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // Optional module docstring

        m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
    }

Compilation>

    1>------ Build started: Project: example, Configuration: Release x64 ------
    1>example.cpp
    1>   Creating library C:\Users\je33894\COMPILATIONS\PythonDLL\example\x64\Release\example.lib and object C:\Users\je33894\COMPILATIONS\PythonDLL\example\x64\Release\example.exp
    1>example.vcxproj -> C:\Users\je33894\COMPILATIONS\PythonDLL\example\x64\Release\example.pyd
    ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

In Spyder:

    import example

OUT (console)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<ipython-input-11-621866f4e6d7>", line 1, in <module>
        import example
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing example: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Check your %Path% contains location of all related DLLs

Comment: how and where should I check the %PATH% @frant

Comment: For example, here:
https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html#:~:text=On%20the%20Windows%20desktop%2C%20right,highlight%20Path%2C%20and%20click%20Edit.

Comment: Now it works: there was one setup issue on my side. I have compiled the code by referencing  to libs of python37 while I was calling the DLL (pyd) using environment that was using python38. Important is to use the same python version in compilation and calling of pyd. Second that was important as advised was to add %PATH%  of DLL. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I was also running into this issue but for me the reason for not finding the dll is because I compiled the pybind11 based extension with mingw gcc, whereas python on windows is compiled with MSVC and so there are some incompatibility issues. The folks over at scipy solved this by linking to -lucrt statically (check their meson build file for full details) when compiling with mingw, but this might not work for everyone (I think ucrt is one of the available mingw gcc versions, but there are others).

Answer (score -1):

I've been through this error and what I found after a lot of investigation:-

issue was in Opencv==4.5.1 build from source with cuda and flag

`cuda_with_fast_math=on`

- I just rebuild OpenCV and disable

`cuda_with_fast_math=off`

- make sure that cv version in .pyd build matching cv version used to import in python
- add to system environment variable Path to `opencv_world451.dll` i.e.

> C:\opencv\install\x64\vc16\bin

and it works for me.